# How can I find the bottleneck in my slow MySQL routine (stored procedure)?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, stored-procedures

I have a routine in MySQL that is very long and has multiple `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE` statements in it with some `IF`s and `REPEAT`s. It's been running fine until lately, where it's hanging an taking over 20 seconds to complete (which is unacceptable considering it used to take 1 second or so).

What is the quickest and easiest way for me to find out where in the routine the bottleneck is coming from? Basically the routine is getting stopped up and some point... how can I find out where that is without breaking apart the routine and testing one-by-one each section?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server) (a free distribution of MySQL with many enhancements), you can make the slow-query log record times for individual queries, using the `log_slow_sp_statements` configuration variable.  See http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/diagnostics/slow_extended_55.html

If you're using stock MySQL, you can add statements in the stored procedure to set a series of session variables to the value returned by the [`SYSDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) function.  Use a different session variable at different points in the SP.  Then after you run the SP in a test execution, you can inspect the values of these session variables to see what section of the SP took the longest.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze the query can see the execution plan of the same. It is not always an easy task but with a bit of reading will find the solution. I leave some useful links

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/explaining-mysqls-explain